# Open a program by a code in Android

Tags: android

Is there any way to open an Application by typing a code (like *#06# views IMEI number) by a JAVA program in Android?

Comment: Why don't you use a normal [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, use an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

```
Context.startActivity(new Intent(this, AppActivityClassName.class)
```